# Computer will no longer load 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, startup, boot-failure, lock-screen

My computer ASUS M5A99X Motherboard, 8GB RAM, Seagate hard drive, ASUS GeForce video card.  I had 12.04 LTS 64bit loaded.

Now when I boot, it will go to the Grub screen, and then reboot, return to the grub screen and lock up.  With a live DVD, it will show the pick language screen and lock up.

Any ideas? It had been operating fine.

Comment: Maybe worthwhile testing the system hardware.  Start with a memory check.

Comment: I want to know whether you had two different Operating systems... ie., Windows and Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a hardware issue as it won't boot the DVD either.  follow the directions for clearing NVRAM on your motherboard, try again. If that doesn't work, you'll likely have to troubleshoot the hardware.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.